# Removing two column entry duplicate permutations in spreadsheets

Tags: formula, libreoffice-calc

In my project, I have a spreadsheet with two columns of string values like so:

```
1 |   A  |  B   |
2 |Blagh | Nagh |
3 |Ipsum | Lorem|
4 |Nagh  | Blagh|
5 |Lorem | Fluff|
```

Each line is unique if ordered, however its permutations are not unique (For instance, A2B2 = B4A4 and so on).

In this project, position does not matter.

Using a spreadsheet program how can I remove these "permutation duplicates"?

(Currently using LibreOffice Calc, but if impossible in any of such software, suggestions regarding using a DataFrame library like Pandas are acceptable.)

Answer (score 1):

I'll try again.

Sort on ColumnA, then ColumnB (if required to preserve the order, add an index column first and sort on that at the end.)

In C1 and copied down to suit:

```
=ROW()<>IF(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(B1,A:A,0))=A1,MAX(ROW(),MATCH(B1,A:A,0)))
```

Filter on ColumnC to delete cells showing `FALSE`.

Comment: Good idea. I'll test it. Do you think that using "Index" I can recover the data automatically and no need for filtering?

Comment: So Far, I got to the filtering of non duplicates. Now, I cannot get the part where I remove the duplicates from the remainder - I've found the indexes of the duplications, ordered them but how to find out which are duplicates?

Comment: Didn't understand this part yet: "From where the numbers start series fill 1 and 2 down to suit"

Comment: No success... After ordering the duplicates are not paired. They are spread out.